# #include <string> in a header the defines some structs. ERROR: string does not define a type

Tags: c++, header, struct, include, types

```
#ifndef STRCUTS_H
#define STRCUTS_H
#include <string>

struct menuEntry 
{ 
    string itemID;    //'string' does not name a type
    string itemName;  //'string' does not name a type
};

#endif
```

I get the same error when I put #include < string> above the header guard. Come to think of it, I've had weird trouble with putting struct definitions in headers before. Must be something I'm not getting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change `string` to `std::string`, i.e.

```
#ifndef STRCUTS_H
#define STRCUTS_H

#include <string>

struct menuEntry 
{ 
    std::string itemID;
    std::string itemName;
};

#endif
```

Comment: or add a `using std::string` or `using namespace std`. Just FYI.

Comment: @KitsuneYMG: no - you should never put `using namespace std` (or `using namespace <anything>` in a header.